# How do I load module from the project in a test script?

Tags: powershell, plugins, visual-studio-2015

[image: project structure]

I'm having trouble loading getting the `Module.psm1` to load in `Module.tests.ps1`.

Here is my `Module.psm1`. I add a return to `Get-Function` just to see if it would get picked up by the test runner.

This is in `Module.psm1`:

```
function Get-Function {
    return $true
}
```

`Module.psd1`:

```
FunctionsToExport = 'Get-Function'
```

`Module.tests.ps1`:

```
Describe "Get-Function" {
    Context "Function Exists" {
        Import-Module .\Module.psm1
        It "Should Return" {
            Get-Function | Should Be $true
        }
    }
}
```

Does the module have to be built and loaded into my module path before I can write tests against it? Or is there a way to reference it's location relative to the test path?

The results I'm seeing in the out put window are:

```
------ Run test started ------
Describing Get-Function
   Context Function Exists
    [-] Should Return 731ms
The term 'Get-Function' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
at line: 12 in C:\Users\Adam\Documents\code\Powershell\TestModuleProject\TestModuleProject\Module.tests.ps1
Tests completed in 731ms
Passed: 0 Failed: 1 Skipped: 0 Pending: 0 
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:08.1834099) ==========
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the working directory (`.`) is different from the directory in which your files reside when you're running the test. You could use `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` to determine the directory of the test script.

[Pester](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/03/12/get-started-with-pester-powershell-unit-testing-framework/) unit tests (which is what your test code and output look like) usually contain a line like this for that purpose:

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

Try changing your test code as follows:

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

Describe "Get-Function" {
    Context "Function Exists" {
        Import-Module "$here\Module.psm1"
        It "Should Return" {
            Get-Function | Should Be $true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me, too, but I had to leave the quotation marks off of the import statement.  **Import-Module $here\Module.psm1**